# Average number of every side in 3D array

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I was wondering if there is any simple way to calculate the average sum from avery side.

Here is my code if anyone knows how to help it would be very nice.

```
using System;

namespace _3D_Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,,] array3D = new int[1, 4, 3] { { { 4, 5, 6 }, { 4, 4, 5 }, 
                                                   { 3, 6, 4 }, { 5, 4, 5 } } };
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1},{2}] : {3}", i, j, k, array3D[i,j,k]);
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

```
Outcome: 
a[0,0,0] : 4
a[0,0,1] : 5
a[0,0,2] : 6
avrg : 5 ///(4+5+6 : 3)
a[0,1,0] : 4
a[0,1,1] : 5
a[0,1,2] : 3
avrg : 4 ///(4+5+3 : 3)
...
```

Comment: What is a "row" in 3d world? A plane or a single line?

Comment: is it called side? for my example 0,0,0 ; 0,0,1 ; 0,0,2

Comment: Im searching the average number of the side 0,0,0; 0,0,1; 0,0,2 and the other 3 sides

Comment: Could you add a data example and the expected outcome? I am struggling to understand your question completly...

Comment: What you call the average is not clear. Do your codes produce what you want?

Comment: I will put what I expect as outcome give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to keep track of all the values for your side. Get average after your K loop.

```
using System.Linq; // on top
using System.Collections.Generic;

...
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        List<int> arr = new List<int>();
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1},{2}] : {3}", i, j, k, array3D[i, j, k]);
            arr.Add(array3D[i, j, k]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Average of side: [{i}, {j}] = {(int)arr.Average()}");
    }
}
```

and the output you get is:

```
a[0,0,0] : 4
a[0,0,1] : 5
a[0,0,2] : 6
Average of side: [0, 0] = 5
a[0,1,0] : 4
a[0,1,1] : 4
a[0,1,2] : 5
Average of side: [0, 1] = 4
a[0,2,0] : 3
a[0,2,1] : 6
a[0,2,2] : 4
Average of side: [0, 2] = 4
a[0,3,0] : 5
a[0,3,1] : 4
a[0,3,2] : 5
Average of side: [0, 3] = 4
```

Comment: When I try to use this code in visual studio it gives me some errors can you post the full code so I can see if I have something missing? (sorry but I don't know much about coding)

Comment: make sure you have using System.Linq; for the Average function.

Comment: my bad. had an extra closing brack on arr.Add() line.

Comment: above the for K loop, you have to initialize it:  List<int> arr = new List<int>();

Comment: "type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: it doesnt change, it still gives me the same error. Never mind, it needed using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: is there a way to round the numbers?

Comment: you can cast them to int.. which is what i do here (int)arr.Average(). You can use Math.Round function as well. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided, this is one of the viable answer.

```
        double avrg = 0; //Add a variable to store the averages
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)

            {
                avrg = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1},{2}] : {3}", i, j, k, array3D[i, j, k]);
                    avrg += array3D[i, j, k]; //sum the values
                }
                avrg = avrg / array3D.GetLength(2); //calculate the average
                Console.WriteLine("avrg: {0}", Math.Round(avrg)); // print the avrg value
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the person that replied first helped me but thanks for this its nice to have two versions of how to do a one task. :)

Comment: do you know how to average them if the number is more than for example 4.50 to 5 to show 5 and if its between 4 and 4.49 to be 4

Comment: just change the Variable type to Double, and use the Math.Round on output

Comment: thank you guys, I didn't expect that much help in this website :D